# Is there a way to eager fetch a lazy relationship through the Predicate API in QueryDSL?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I am using the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` from Spring Data JPA project, and I am facing the need to eager fetch a lazy relation. I know that I can use a native JPA-QL query in the Repository interface, or even used the JPAQLQuery from Query DSL, but I was intrigued if this is even possible in order to facilitate building queries for future needs.

Comment: What do you mean by if this is even possible? `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` provides a small subset of Querydsl functionality, for more you need to write queries yourself.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I was trying to think of a way of avoiding that and using the Predicate API, to build more complex queries, that allow me to fetch relationships at will, append other predicates, thus not having to create a method with an annotated query for a specific purpose in the Repository interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I had to fetch join a Collection while using Predicates and QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

What I did was to create a **custom repository implementation** to add a method that allowed me to define the entities that should be fetched.

*Don't be daunted by the amount of code in here, it's actually very simple and you will need to do very few changes to use it on your application*

**This is the interface of the custom repository**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JoinFetchCapableRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends     JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors);
}
```

**JoinDescriptor**

```
public class JoinDescriptor {
    public final EntityPath path;
    public final JoinType type;

    private JoinDescriptor(EntityPath path, JoinType type) {
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor innerJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.INNERJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor join(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.JOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor leftJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.LEFTJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor rightJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.RIGHTJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor fullJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.FULLJOIN);
    }
}
```

**Implementation of the custom repository**

```
public class JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl <T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JoinFetchCapableRepository<T, ID> {

    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    public JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);
        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        this.builder = new PathBuilder<>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors) {
        JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
        JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createFetchQuery(predicate, joinDescriptors));

        Long total = countQuery.count();
        List<T> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.list(path) : Collections.<T> emptyList();

        return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, total);
    }

    protected JPQLQuery createFetchQuery(Predicate predicate, JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors) {
        JPQLQuery query = querydsl.createQuery(path);
        for(JoinDescriptor joinDescriptor: joinDescriptors)
            join(joinDescriptor, query);
        return query.where(predicate);
    }

    private JPQLQuery join(JoinDescriptor joinDescriptor, JPQLQuery query) {
        switch(joinDescriptor.type) {
            case DEFAULT:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cross join not supported");
            case INNERJOIN:
                query.innerJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
                break;
            case JOIN:
                query.join(joinDescriptor.path);
                break;
            case LEFTJOIN:
                query.leftJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
                break;
            case RIGHTJOIN:
                query.rightJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
                break;
            case FULLJOIN:
                query.fullJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
                break;
        }
        return query.fetch();
    }
}
```

**Factory to create the custom repositories, replacing the default QueryDslJpaRepository**

```
public class JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
    private static class JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl<>(getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType()), entityManager);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return JoinFetchCapableRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Last step is to change the jpa configuration so it uses this factory instead of the default one:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      factory-class="com.mycompany.utils.spring.data.JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

Then you can use it from your service layer like this:

```
public Page<ETicket> list(ETicketSearch eTicket, Pageable pageable) {
    return eticketRepository.findAll(like(eTicket), pageable, JoinDescriptor.leftJoin(QETicket.eTicket.order));
}
```

By using JoinDescriptor you will be able to specify what you want to join based on your service needs.

I was able to do this thanks to the Murali's response here: [Spring Data JPA and Querydsl to fetch subset of columns using bean/constructor projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300465/spring-data-and-querydsl-to-fetch-subset-of-columns-using-bean-constructor-proje) Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I ended up working with the Criteria approach, I will test this approach on a smaller project I have for testing stuff. Thanks for your effort...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to extend JoinDescriptor to include onetomany (i.e SetPath) instead of only EntityPath?

Comment: @AngelVillalain "Although I ended up working with the Criteria approach" - Can you explain how did you get it to work?

Comment: @Pranjal, sorry that was long time ago, I don't remember the details right now. I will try, and if I remember I will update the answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Spring data [has introduced JPA Entity Graph support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph).  Beware that is [does not currently work with graphs that are traversed via EmbeddedIds](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9298).

Comment: When this question was asked, there was no support for JPA Entity Graph, well it was still in development to be precise. But now that this is available I think this question should consider this as a solution.