# Spring Data JPA and Querydsl to fetch subset of columns using bean/constructor projection

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have an entity class as below:

```java
@Entity
public class UserDemo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String createdBy;
    @Version
    private int version;

    /***
     *
     * Getters and setters
     */
}
```

Using Spring Data JPA and Querydsl how do I fetch a page of *UserDemo* with only `id` and `username` properties populated? I need to use paging as well as searching. In short I would like to achieve the same result as

```java
Page<UserDemo> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

but with limited field of *UserDemo* populated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like custom repository implementation is the way to go for now until something similar available in spring data.

I have gone through http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Here is my implementation which works. However it would be good to have this method available directly in Spring-Data-JPA

**Step 1: Intermediate interface for shared behavior**

```
public interface CustomQueryDslJpaRepository <T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
    /**
     * Returns a {@link org.springframework.data.domain.Page} of entities matching the given {@link com.mysema.query.types.Predicate}.
     * This also uses provided projections ( can be JavaBean or constructor or anything supported by QueryDSL
     * @param constructorExpression this constructor expression will be used for transforming query results
     * @param predicate
     * @param pageable
     * @return
     */
    Page<T> findAll(FactoryExpression<T> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Step 2: Implementation of intermediate interface**

```
public class CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements CustomQueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    //All instance variables are available in super, but they are private
    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    public CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager,
                                 EntityPathResolver resolver) {

        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        this.builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(FactoryExpression<T> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
        JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate));

        Long total = countQuery.count();
        List<T> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.list(factoryExpression) : Collections.<T> emptyList();

        return new PageImpl<T>(content, pageable, total);
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Create a custom repository factory to replace the default**

```
public class CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
    private static class CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl<>(getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType()), entityManager);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return CustomQueryDslJpaRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Use the custom repository factory**

Using annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

OR using XML

```
<repositories base-package="com.acme.repository"  factory-class="com.acme.CustomQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

**Note: Don't place custom repository interface and implementation in the same directory as base-package. If you are placing then exclude them from scanning otherwise spring will try to create beans for them**

**Sample usage**

```
public interface UserDemoRepository extends CustomQueryDslJpaRepository<UserDemo, Long>{
}

public class UserDemoService {
    @Inject 
    UserDemoRepository userDemoRepository;

    public Page<User> findAll(UserSearchCriteria userSearchCriteria, Pageable pageable) {
        QUserDemo user = QUserDemo.userDemo;
        return userDemoRepository.findAll(Projections.bean(UserDemo.class, user.id, user.username), UserPredicate.defaultUserSearch(userSearchCriteria), pageable);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is FactoryExpression is it custom class or pre-defined.

Comment: FactoryExpression is base class for Projections in Querydsl. http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/FactoryExpression.html

Comment: I get a `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property find found for type <MY_TYPE_NAME>` when I tried this. Why is that? <MY_TYPE_NAME> of course stands for my Entity type.

Comment: Ok I was able to solve my problem after some trying. I noticed that you need to annotate the custom interface with `@NoRepositoryBean` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21630123/1969096), which also references back this post :). Thanks for your post @Murali. Very helpful.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27764980/2796922) helped me to know how to specify attributes of contained entities using `Projections`.

Comment: For anyone arriving here, there is a feature request that Murali raised, which can be found at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-393

Comment: Docs link is out of date, this appears to be the new location: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 9):

For more recent versions of Spring Data, I couldn't get the accepted answer to work without hitting issues, but found that going down the route from the Spring Data docs, does work by revising that answer as follows:

**1. The repository interface**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface QueryDslPredicateAndProjectionExecutor<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    <PROJ> Page<PROJ> customFindWithProjection(FactoryExpression<PROJ> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**2. The repository implementation**

```
public class QueryDslJpaEnhancedRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements QueryDslPredicateAndProjectionExecutor<T, ID> {

    //All instance variables are available in super, but they are private
    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    public QueryDslJpaEnhancedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public QueryDslJpaEnhancedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager,
                                 EntityPathResolver resolver) {

        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);
        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        this.builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public <PROJ> Page<PROJ> customFindWithProjection(FactoryExpression<PROJ> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
        JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate));

        Long total = countQuery.count();
        List<PROJ> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.list(factoryExpression) : Collections.<PROJ>emptyList();

        return new PageImpl<PROJ>(content, pageable, total);
    }
}
```

**3. Setting the default repository implementation**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    repositoryBaseClass=QueryDslJpaEnhancedRepositoryImpl.class,
    basePackageClasses=SomeRepository.class)
```

Comment: do you have a code base for this somewhere, Is PROJ means my projection interface, i get some compilation errors , pls share any github site or anywhere i can refer to...

Comment: actually after i implemented, though dsl part works , results i get are not projected but whole object. so back to square one.. pls let me know if you have sample codes somewhere for query dsl + projection

Comment: And i am using 1.4.0.RELEASE spring boot version

Comment: @NealeU in your repository impl count() and list(FactoryExpression) are in 3.7, how do I make this work in 4.1.4?

Comment: Hi @techRunner, you'll have to look at the QueryDSL 4 docs for the new methods, although you'll probably find the key changes at http://blog.anthavio.net/2015/11/upgrading-querydsl-3-to-4.html.

Answer (score 6):

For the current versions of Spring Data (1.11.1) and QueryDSL (4), you have to change the customFindWithProjection method implementation like this:

```
@Override
public <PROJ> Page<PROJ> customFindWithProjection(FactoryExpression<PROJ> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

    final JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = createCountQuery(predicate);
    JPQLQuery<PROJ> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression));

    long total = countQuery.fetchCount();
    List<PROJ> content = pageable == null || total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.fetch() : Collections.<PROJ> emptyList();

    return new PageImpl<PROJ>(content, pageable, total);
}
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve the same result with just a bit of code.

```
public class Queryable<T> extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T> {

  private static final EntityPathResolver resolver = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

  private final Querydsl querydsl;

  public Queryable(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
      this(JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(domainClass, entityManager), 
           entityManager);
  }

  private Queryable(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
      EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver, null);
    EntityPath<T> path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
    PathBuilder<?> builder = new PathBuilder<>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
  }

  public Page<T> findAll(Expression<T> expression, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
     JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
     JPQLQuery<T> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable,
                          createQuery(predicate).select(expression));
     List<T> dtos = query.fetch();
     return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(dtos, pageable, countQuery::fetchCount);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
class UserDemoRepository
    private static final QUserDemo q = QUserDemo.userDemo;
    private static final QBean<UserDemo> PROJECTION = Projections.bean(UserDemo.class, 
            q.id, q.username);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    public Page<UserDemo> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return new Queryable<UserDemo>(UserDemo.class, entityManager)
               .findAll(PROJECTION, predicate, pageable);
  }
}
```

(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960209/1833472)

Comment: nice, very simple and effective compared to the other answers. I modified this approach slightly to make the new method(s) available in the existing interfaces. I created a customized BaseRepository that made an EntityManager instance available to all my existing repository interfaces. Then I used default methods to call the findAll() method from those repositories, passing the EntityManager from the customized BaseRepository

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works and does only select the projected values from the database.

Answer (score 2):

As a (albeit very ugly and inefficient) workaround, I simply retrieved a regular `Page` containing the entities from my repository and manually mapped them to a projection in the controller like so:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/columns")
public Page<ColumnProjection> getColumns(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Column.class) final Predicate predicate,
                                         final Pageable pageable) {
 Page<Column> filteredColumns = columnRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
 List<ColumnProjection> filteredColumnProjections = new ArrayList<>();
 filteredColumns.forEach(c -> filteredColumnProjections.add(new ColumnProjectionImpl(c)));
 return new PageImpl<>(filteredColumnProjections, pageable, filteredColumnProjections.size());
}
```

Where `ColumnProjectionImpl` is a class implementing my `ColumnProjection` interface.

This was the easiest solution I could come up with while not having to adapt my existing ColumnRepository.

Comment: That will fetch all columns from the database, which is inefficient if you have a lot of columns and/or rows.

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into the same issue myself. 
In short - we have to specify custom repository factory bean, that tell to use our custom repo as another "fragment".
So i overrided factory.getRepositoryFragments to include a custom projection predicate implementation(IMHO it resolves the issue in the question [No property found for type… custom Spring Data repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467894/no-property-found-for-type-custom-spring-data-repository/41490008)).

updated code, based on all previous answers :

**1.QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactory**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.EntityPathResolver;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragment;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

import static org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslUtils.QUERY_DSL_PRESENT;

public class QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityPathResolver entityPathResolver;

    public QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.entityPathResolver = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments getRepositoryFragments(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments fragments = super.getRepositoryFragments(metadata);

        boolean isQueryDslRepository = QUERY_DSL_PRESENT
                && QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepository.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getRepositoryInterface());

        if (isQueryDslRepository) {

            JpaEntityInformation<?, Serializable> entityInformation = getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());

            Object querydslFragment = getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl.class, entityInformation,
                    entityManager, entityPathResolver, null);

            fragments = fragments.append(RepositoryFragment.implemented(querydslFragment));
        }

        return fragments;

    }
}
```

**2.QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactoryBean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

public class QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {
    public QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

**3.QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepository** here we add new methods, that use projections etc...

```
import com.querydsl.core.types.FactoryExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

import java.util.List;

public interface QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepository<T> {
    <Projection> Page<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression);
    <Projection> List<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression);
    <Projection> List<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression);
}
```

**4.QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl** here we implement the repository interface methods

```
import com.querydsl.core.QueryResults;
import com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath;
import com.querydsl.core.types.FactoryExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.PathBuilder;
import com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.EntityPathResolver;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

public class QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl<T> extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T> implements QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepository<T> {
    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final Querydsl querydsl;


    public QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver, null);

        EntityPath<T> path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        PathBuilder<T> builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    public QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver, CrudMethodMetadata metadata) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver, metadata);
        EntityPath<T> path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        PathBuilder<T> builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public <Projection> List<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression) {
        return createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression).fetch();
    }

    @Override
    public <Projection> List<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression) {
        JPQLQuery<Projection> query = createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression);
        querydsl.applySorting(sort, query);

        return query.fetch();
    }

    @Override
    public <Projection> Page<Projection> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, FactoryExpression<Projection> factoryExpression) {
        JPQLQuery<Projection> query = createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression);
        querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query);
        querydsl.applySorting(pageable.getSort(), query);

        QueryResults<Projection> queryResults = query.fetchResults();
        return new PageImpl<>(queryResults.getResults(), pageable, queryResults.getTotal());
    }
}
```

**5.Example entity**

```
@Entity
public class Example extends Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String surname;
    @Column
    private Integer year;

    public Example() {
    }
    public Long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getSurname() {return surname;}
    public void setSurname(String surname) {this.surname= surname;}
    public Integer getYear() {return year;}
    public void setSurname(Integer year) {this.year= year;}
}
```

**6.Example repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long>, QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepository<Example> { }
```

**7.Example usage**
configuration :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = QuerydslPredicateProjectionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

***typical usage :***

```
//get list of entities only with year field value set - memory consuming
List<Example> years = repository.findAll(predicate, Projections.fields(Example.class, QExample.example.year)); 
//get list of tuples - looks nicer - less memory consuming
List<Tuple> years = repository.findAll(predicate, Projections.tuple(QExample.example.year));
//get list of integers - nice :)
List<Integer> years = repository.findAll(predicate, Projections.constructor(Integer.class, QExample.example.year));
```

Answer (score 1):

*1. CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

public class CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {
    public CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new CustomJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

*2. CustomJpaRepositoryFactory*

```
import static org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslUtils.QUERY_DSL_PRESENT;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;

public class CustomJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {
    public CustomJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        if(QUERY_DSL_PRESENT) {
            Class<?> repositoryInterface = metadata.getRepositoryInterface();
            if(CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface)) {
                return CustomQueryDslJpaRepository.class;
            } else  if(QueryDslPredicateExecutor.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface)) {
                return QueryDslJpaRepository.class;
            }
        }
        return SimpleJpaRepository.class;
    }
}
```

*3. CustomQueryDslJpaRepository*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.EntityPathResolver;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver;

import com.querydsl.core.QueryResults;
import com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath;
import com.querydsl.core.types.FactoryExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Projections;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.PathBuilder;
import com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery;

public class CustomQueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    public CustomQueryDslJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public CustomQueryDslJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);

        EntityPath<T> path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        PathBuilder<T> builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    public <DTO> Page<DTO> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, FactoryExpression<DTO> factoryExpression) {
        JPQLQuery<DTO> query = createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression);
        querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query);
        querydsl.applySorting(pageable.getSort(), query);

        QueryResults<DTO> queryResults = query.fetchResults();
        return new PageImpl<>(queryResults.getResults(), pageable, queryResults.getTotal());
    }
}
```

*4. CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor*

```
import com.querydsl.core.types.FactoryExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;

public interface CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
    <DTO> Page<DTO> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, FactoryExpression<DTO> factoryExpression);
}
```

*5. example*

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    ...
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)


public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> implements CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor<Product> {
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This was the very useful reference which worked for my requirement to have a custom base repository for a subset of my repositories which need to support  QueryDSL predicate api with NamedEntityGraphs