# Spring Data JPA QueryDslPredicateExecutor find distinct results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a Spring Data & JPA QueryDSL based project in which I have many repository interfaces extending QueryDslPredicateExecutor like below:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Product> {
}
```

I am performing `findAll()` queries with `BooleanExpression`s all over my application to fetch data. However I now need to find the distinct results of a query based on a particular column.

I am also using Projections & Custom repositories in some cases to select particular columns based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18300465/1969096).

Is there a way to `select distinct` so that I only get the distinct values of a particular column for a query, based on any of the above approaches?

Answer (score 4):

Today I've encountered the same issue and it seems that there's no direct repository approach to solve it.

I ended using [Querydsl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/Querydsl.html) in order to accomplish what I wanted: being able to use `Page<T> findAll(Predicate var1, Pageable var2);` using distinct.

A simple snippet:

```
public Page<LocalizedMessage> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
  QMessage qMessage = QMessage.message;

  Querydsl querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, new PathBuilder<>(Message.class, qMessage.getMetadata()));
  JPAQuery countQuery = querydsl.createQuery(qMessage).distinct().where(predicate);
  JPAQuery query = querydsl.createQuery(qMessage).distinct().where(predicate);
  querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query);
  return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.fetch(), pageable, countQuery::fetchCount);
}
```

This code is based on [QuerydslJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaRepository.html)'s `findAll(Predicate, Pageable)` method. I presumed that it could be easy to extend this repository in order to add `findAllDistinct` methods using `JPQLQuery.distinct()`.

I've filed a [feature request at spring-data's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1289).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Querydsl queries directly in your repository you can call `query.distinct()` to get distinct results.