# No property found for type... custom Spring Data repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a custom Spring repository. I have the interface:

```
public interface FilterRepositoryCustom {
    List<User> filterBy(String role);
}
```

the implementation:

```
public class FilterRepositoryImpl implements FilterRepositoryCustom {
...
}
```

and the "main" repository, extending my custom repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, FilterRepositoryCustom {
...
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot and, according to the [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/):

> By default, Spring Boot will enable JPA repository support and look in
>   the package (and its subpackages) where @SpringBootApplication is
>   located.

When I run my application, I get this error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filterBy found for type User!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating **`FilterRepositoryImpl`** but you are using it in **`UserRepository`**. You need to create **`UserRepositoryImpl`** to make this work.

[Read this doc for more detail](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Basically

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    List<User> filterBy(String role);
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
...
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom {
...
}
```

**Spring Data 2.x update**
This answer was written for Spring 1.x. As [Matt Forsythe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467894/no-property-found-for-type-custom-spring-data-repository/41490008?noredirect=1#comment82037254_41490008) pointed out, the naming expectations changed with Spring Data 2.0. The implementation changed from `the-final-repository-interface-name-with-an-additional-Impl-suffix` to `the-custom-interface-name-with-an-additional-Impl-suffix`.

So in this case, the name of the implementation would be: `UserRepositoryCustomImpl`.

Comment: While I agree that this works (and have seen it in action), I am having a hard time reconciling this behavior with the linked documentation, which explicitly uses a `CustomizedUserRepositoryImpl` on a repository named `UserRepository`.  The docs then go further (example 29) to use `HumanRepositoryImpl` AND `ContactRepositoryImpl` together on `UserRepository`.  They seem to indicate that the important thing is for the fragment implementation name to match the fragment interface name, rather than the base repository name, but that is clearly not the case from what I have seen.  I am confused...

Comment: Did some more digging and answered my own question: the requirement that the implementation name be based on the base repository name is only true for older (1.x) versions of spring-data.  In version 2.x of spring-data, this requirement changes.  In 2.x, the impl name must follow the custom interface name.

Comment: You saved my time and made me happy! Thanks, naming with Spring Data really maters, event for tests.

Comment: And also packages for xxxRepository & xxxRepositoryImpl matters. 
if xxxRepository is in com.test package then xxxRepositoryImpl sholuld be in com.test.impl

Comment: Same issue in Spring's docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

CustomizedUserRepository, CustomizedUserRepositoryImpl and UserRepository, but it doesn't work, because CustomizedUserRepositoryImpl should be UserRepositoryImpl

Thanks for solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I couldn't see the difference at first :) Finally I realized `UserRepositoryImpl` instead of `FilterRepositoryImpl`

Comment: @Bala You're absolutely right !! I had the same issue, the files were named as expected, but they were in the same package. When creating a "XXXRepositoryImpl" package, it worked like a charm :)

Comment: @mattforsythe's 2nd comment should also be part of the accepted answer

Comment: I also had a similar issue, 2.X of spring-data-jpa, custom implementation repository class name must follow it custom interface and not root repository, also both interfaces and implementation class must be in the same package.

Comment: Did you mean to write `public class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom`? (UserRepository **Custom** Impl, as opposed to UserRepositoryImpl)

Comment: Your custom repository's name is important! 
interface must be: 
BeanName + Repository + Custom, and implement class name must be: BeanName + Repository + Custom + Impl。For example: your bean name is City, so: interface name is :CityRepositoryCustom, and implement class name is :CityRepositoryCustomImpl. finally:  interface CityRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<City, String>, CityRepositoryCustom

Answer (score 6):

Another way this error can happen if the impl class for FilterRepositoryCustom isn't picked up in your spring configuration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {RepoPackageMarker.class, FilterRepositoryCustomImpl.class})
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Please check if your packages structure looks like this

```
custom
   impl
      - FilterRepositoryCustomImpl.class
- FilterRepositoryCustom.class
```

Because when I try to use my custom repo it doesn't see the implementation. (implementation should be in the same package or in sub-packages for Spring to see it)

Maybe it helps somebody (ノ^∇^)

Comment: "implementation should be in the same package or in sub-packages for Spring to see it" very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a must that the `customMethod()` in the CustomRepository can only have parameters defined that are either

1.Entity class name - `customMethod(User user)`,

2.Entity class attributes - `customMethod(String firstName)`, here firstName is an attribute of User Entity class.

Can I not have something like customMethod(CustomCriteria criteria), the criteria class contain the various attributes that are used to construct a dynamic query.

e.g. `getStatusByCriteria(CustomCriteria criteria), CustomCriteria` is a simple pojo annotated with @Component so that spring identifies it.

When I tried this I get an error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property criteria found for type UserRepository!

Answer (score 2):

The most important part of the class name that corresponds to the fragment interface is the Impl postfix.

Comment: I can't believe on that, it works

Answer (score 1):

for me the keys was

1. @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)
2. @NoRepositoryBean annotation on interface

follow the docs for your spring ver
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories

so as result i have:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SliceRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {..}

public class SliceRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements SliceRepository<T, ID> {..}


@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"com.some.servicename.repository"},
        repositoryBaseClass = SliceRepositoryImpl.class
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error. It occured because I had configured elasticSearch repository with package

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("some.package")
```

Next I moved MyElasticSearchRepository from package 'some.package' to another, but didn't change configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a project of mine. I solved the problem by adding a line in my **pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>com/my/package/entities/*.java</include>
            <include>com/my/package/repositories/*.java</include>
            <include>com/my/package/repositories/impl/*.java</include> <!-- add this -->
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -5):

Old way:

```
Entity aThing = repository.findOne(1L);
```

New way:

```
Optional<Entity> aThing = repository.findById(1L);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)