# PropertyReferenceException on custom repository Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have normal interface DAO and i wanted to create some custom methods. But then i get PropertyReferenceException exception. Here are my classes :

**LeadDao**

```
public interface LeadDao extends JpaRepository<LeadEntity, Integer>, LeadDaoCustom {

}
```

**LeadDaoCustom**

```
public interface LeadDaoCustom {

    public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getLeadNumberInDateRange();

}
```

**LeadDaoImpl**

```
@Repository
public class LeadDaoImpl implements LeadDaoCustom {

@Autowired
LeadDao leadDao;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.quantox.leadex.core.persistance.dao.LeadDao#getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange()
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getLeadNumberInDateRange() {
    Query q1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT addeddate, \r\n" + 
            "                      Count(DISTINCT campaignid, email) AS count \r\n" + 
            "               FROM   leads \r\n" + 
            "               GROUP  BY addeddate"); 
    org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery =((org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateQuery)q1) .getHibernateQuery(); 
    return (Map<LocalDateTime, Integer>) hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE).uniqueResult();
}

}
```

In my service class i am using this :

```
@Autowired
    private LeadDao leadDao;
```

But when i start application i get this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getLeadNumberInDateRange found for type LeadEntity!
```

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467894/no-property-found-for-type-custom-spring-data-repository

Comment: i saw that but he was wrong with naming of classes, i did that as it should be done

Comment: i dont think you need that @Repository annotation on the LeadDaoImpl  class.