# In Spring Data JPA FindBy method is not working and “No Property Found for Type” Exception is not occurring.

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring boot and JPA, I created a simple JPA repository and was trying to implement custom findBy method but it always returns null, Even if I use any dummy name after findBy which is not a property of my class it dose not show any error.Although default findBy methods are working fine.

```
package com.example.demo;

   import java.util.List;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   @Service
   public class EmployeeService {

    // This is my service class.
    // Creating employee repository
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo er;

    // This is the method I want to implement
    public List<Employee> getByname(String name) {

        return er.findByName(name);
    }

}

//This is my Repository 

package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
        // Name is a property of Employee class
    public List<Employee> findByName(String name);
        // Dummy is not a property of Employee class
    public List<Employee> findByDummy(String name);


}
```

It should give an error for findByDummy method, but it is not giving. Is it considering this interface as general interface and allowing any declaration.
For findByName it is returning null. It should search based on name and for findByDummy it should show error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467894/no-property-found-for-type-custom-spring-data-repository

Comment: @prafull try annotating the `EmployeeRepo` as `@Repository` also check if configuration class is annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add @Repository Annotation to your Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
        // Name is a property of Employee class
    public List<Employee> findByName(String name);
        // Dummy is not a property of Employee class
    public List<Employee> findByDummy(String name);


}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!! It did my work :) can we do same with RepositoryRestResource? I mean to use custom query method?

Comment: Please check this question also--    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063427/can-we-create-custom-query-using-spring-data-rest-while-using-repositoryrestres

Answer (score 0):

The @Repository annotation was not my issue. My issue was thinking I was using a URL parameters.

I had the following method in my JPA repository:

```
Optional<Sample> findByEpisodeId(String episodeId);
```

Then, I had the following method in a Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/sample/{episodeId}")
    Sample getSampleBy(@PathVariable String episodeId) {
        return sampleService.findByEpisodeId(episodeId); // sampleService uses the jpa method
    }
```

The request I was sending was `/sample/episodeId=12345`.

It should have just been `/sample/12345`.