# Can we create custom Query using Spring Data REST while using @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am new to spring boot, I was trying to create a simple REST service using Spring-boot JPA. First I used simple `@Repository` which works fine, I can write custom Query method for the properties defined in my class. But when I use `@RepositoryRestResource` I am not able to create custom Query methods. Basic finding on  primary key and other operations are happening but I can not create any custom Query.

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    int isbn;
    String name;
    String author;
    double price;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

This is Repository

```
package com.example.demo.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.Model.Book;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "books", path = "books")
public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

    //I want this query to work same as it does for primary Key id.
    public Book findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    //Same for this
    public Book findByIsbn(@Param("isbn") String isbn);    

}
```

Since I am not mapping any url for searching by name, I am trying to search like this `localhost:8080/books/?name=java` Is it correct?
For above url it simply behaves like `localhost:8080/books` and ignore subsequent part and provides all books details.
 I just want to have two classes and perform all basic rest operation and create custom Query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/    https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-data-rest-example/

Comment: Thanks! It is really helpful

Comment: So is your question answered?

Comment: yes.. I was accessing it wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

you need add the therm "search" and the method name in yout uri, like this:

localhost:8080/books/search/findByName?name=java