# Returning a Join of Entity A and Entity B and store in Entity C in Spring JPA without JQL/HQL

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entites:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
       @Column
       private String employeeName;

       @Column
       private Integer employeeId;

       @OnetoMany
       private Set<Account> accounts;
}

@Entity
public class Account {
       @Column
       private String bankName;

       @Column
       private Integer accountNumber; 
}


public class EmployeeAccountRecords {
       private String employeeName;
       private Integer accountNumber;
}
```

I want to get paginated results of join of Employee and Account and store the value in objects of EmployeeAccountRecords class. Further I would also like to pass sorting/filter to the repository implementing this.

Can this be done without writing queries in JPQL/HQL, may be using JPA specification etc, any other components ?

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

Thank you.

PS: result object is using only a subset of result set from the join values.

Answer (score 0):

Without using JPQL/HQL, the other two options I see are Spring Data JPA Specifications and QueryDsl.

As per the links [Support projections on query methods that take a dynamic query type Specification or Querydsl Predicate](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1033) and [Add support for QueryDSL projections in JPA repositories](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-393)
 they don't have support for Projections yet.

But they do have link that shows how to extend repository and support these features in querydsl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300465/spring-data-and-querydsl-to-fetch-subset-of-columns-using-bean-constructor-proje and other one is [specification-with-projection](https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection) and might help.