# Replacing deprecated QuerydslJpaRepository with QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I needed some custom QueryDSL enabled query methods and followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300465/spring-data-jpa-and-querydsl-to-fetch-subset-of-columns-using-bean-constructor-p/35087403#35087403).

That worked great, but after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1 (which upgrades Spring Data), I've found that `QuerydslJpaRepository` has been deprecated.
Simply replacing it with `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` - which the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaRepository.html) tells me to use - leads to an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class
>   [...ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl] must be an instance of
>   interface
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryImplementation

...but implementing `JpaRepositoryImplementation` would mean that I have to implement all the standard CRUD methods, which I obviously don't want.
So if I remove the `repositoryBaseClass` config from `@EnableJpaRepositories`, to treat this just like a repository fragment with implementation, it will try to instantiate the fragment, even though it is marked with `@NoRepositoryBean`, giving me the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query
>   for method public abstract java.util.Optional
>   ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepository.findOneProjectedBy(com.querydsl.core.types.Expression,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)!
>   At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in
>   query.
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s)
>   provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.

Abriged version of source:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class, repositoryBaseClass = ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class DatabaseConfig {}
```

_

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepository<T> extends QuerydslBinderCustomizer<EntityPath<T>>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    @NonNull
    <P> Page<P> findPageProjectedBy(@NonNull Expression<P> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, 
            @NonNull Pageable pageable);

    @NonNull
    <P> Optional<P> findOneProjectedBy(@NonNull Expression<P> factoryExpression, @NonNull Predicate predicate);

    @Override
    default void customize(@NonNull QuerydslBindings bindings, @NonNull EntityPath<T> root){
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

_

```
public class ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID>
implements ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepository<T> {

    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    public ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(@NonNull JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, @NonNull EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public ProjectingQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl(@NonNull JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, @NonNull EntityManager entityManager,
                                           @NonNull EntityPathResolver resolver) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);

        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        PathBuilder<T> builder = new PathBuilder<>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public <P> Page<P> findPageProjectedBy(@NonNull Expression<P> factoryExpression, Predicate predicate, 
        @NonNull Pageable pageable) {

        final JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = createCountQuery(predicate);
        JPQLQuery<P> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression));

        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.fetch(), pageable, countQuery::fetchCount);
    }

    @Override
    public <P> Optional<P> findOneProjectedBy(@NonNull Expression<P> factoryExpression, @NonNull Predicate predicate) {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(createQuery(predicate).select(factoryExpression).from(path).fetchOne());
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException ex) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(ex.getMessage(), 1, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **Spring Boot 2.1.1** the following solution may help you. The key is to extend `JpaRepositoryFactory` and override the method `getRepositoryFragments(RepositoryMetadata metadata)`. In this method you can provide base (or more specific fragment) implementations for any custom repository which should be taken for every extending repository.

Let me show you an example:

**QueryableReadRepository:**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface QueryableReadRepository<T> extends Repository<T, String> {

  List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate);

  List<T> findAll(Sort sort);

  List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort);

  List<T> findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);

  List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);

  Page<T> findAll(Pageable page);

  Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable page);

  Optional<T> findOne(Predicate predicate);

  boolean exists(Predicate predicate);
}
```

The following interface combines different repositories.

**DataRepository:**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DataRepository<T>
    extends CrudRepository<T, String>, QueryableReadRepository<T> {
}
```

Now your specific domain repos can extend from DataRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends DataRepository<UserEntity> {

}
```

**QueryableReadRepositoryImpl:**

```
@Transactional
public class QueryableReadRepositoryImpl<T> extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T>
    implements QueryableReadRepository<T> {

  private static final EntityPathResolver resolver = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

  private final EntityPath<T> path;
  private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
  private final Querydsl querydsl;

  public QueryableReadRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
      EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver, null);
    this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
    this.builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<T> findOne(Predicate predicate) {
    return super.findOne(predicate);
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>... orders) {
    return super.findAll(orders);
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort) {
    return executeSorted(createQuery(predicate).select(path), sort);
  }

  @Override
  public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
    return super.findAll(predicate, pageable);
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate) {
    return super.findAll(predicate);
  }

  public List<T> findAll(Sort sort) {
    return executeSorted(createQuery().select(path), sort);
  }

  @Override
  public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    final JPQLQuery<?> countQuery = createCountQuery();
    JPQLQuery<T> query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery().select(path));

    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
        query.distinct().fetch(), 
        pageable,
        countQuery::fetchCount);
  }

  private List<T> executeSorted(JPQLQuery<T> query, Sort sort) {
    return querydsl.applySorting(sort, query).distinct().fetch();
  }
}
```

**CustomRepositoryFactoryBean**:

```
public class CustomRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, I>, S, I>
    extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, I> {

  public CustomRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
    super(repositoryInterface);
  }

  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new CustomRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }
```

**CustomRepositoryFactory**:

```
public class CustomRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public CustomRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  protected RepositoryFragments getRepositoryFragments(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    RepositoryFragments fragments = super.getRepositoryFragments(metadata);

    if (QueryableReadRepository.class.isAssignableFrom(
        metadata.getRepositoryInterface())) {

      JpaEntityInformation<?, Serializable> entityInformation = 
          getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());

      Object queryableFragment = getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(
          QueryableReadRepositoryImpl.class, entityInformation, entityManager);

      fragments = fragments.append(RepositoryFragment.implemented(queryableFragment));
    }

    return fragments;
  }
```

**Main class:**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class App {
}
```

This has the advantage that you provide only one (fragment) implementation for a custom repo. The base repository implementation is still Spring's default implementation. The example provided a new repo but you can probably also just override the default implementation of `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` in `CustomRepositoryFactory`

Comment: can you please let me know what is `OrderSpecifier`? what is the import statement for it?

Answer (score 3):

In Spring Data JPA 2.1.6 the constructor of `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` has changed.
I present here an alternative approach using a wrapper to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960209/3351474. This makes the solution independent from the internals of Spring Data JPA. Three classes have to be implemented.

As an example I take here a customized Querydsl implementation using always the `creationDate` of an entity as sort criteria if nothing is passed. I assume in this example that this column exists in some `@MappedSuperClass` for all entities. Use generated static metadata in real life instead the hard coded string "creationDate".

As first the wrapped delegating all `CustomQuerydslJpaRepositoryIml` delegating all methods to the `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor`:

```
/**
 * Customized Querydsl JPA repository to apply custom filtering and sorting logic.
 *
 */
public class CustomQuerydslJpaRepositoryIml<T> implements QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    private final QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor querydslPredicateExecutor;

    public CustomQuerydslJpaRepositoryIml(QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor querydslPredicateExecutor) {
        this.querydslPredicateExecutor = querydslPredicateExecutor;
    }

    private Sort applyDefaultOrder(Sort sort) {
        if (sort.isUnsorted()) {
            return Sort.by("creationDate").ascending();
        }
        return sort;
    }

    private Pageable applyDefaultOrder(Pageable pageable) {
        if (pageable.getSort().isUnsorted()) {
            Sort defaultSort = Sort.by(AuditableEntity_.CREATION_DATE).ascending();
            pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), defaultSort);
        }
        return pageable;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findOne(Predicate predicate) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findOne(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(predicate, applyDefaultOrder(sort));
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?>... orders) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(predicate, orders);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>... orders) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(orders);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(predicate, applyDefaultOrder(pageable));
    }

    @Override
    public long count(Predicate predicate) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.count(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(Predicate predicate) {
        return querydslPredicateExecutor.exists(predicate);
    }
}
```

Next the `CustomJpaRepositoryFactory` doing the magic and providing the Querydsl wrapper class instead of the default one. The default one is passed as parameter and wrapped.

```
/**
 * Custom JpaRepositoryFactory allowing to support a custom QuerydslJpaRepository.
 *
 */
public class CustomJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link JpaRepositoryFactory}.
     *
     * @param entityManager must not be {@literal null}
     */
    public CustomJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments getRepositoryFragments(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        final RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments[] modifiedFragments = {RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments.empty()};
        RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments fragments = super.getRepositoryFragments(metadata);
        // because QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor is using som internal classes only a wrapper can be used.
        fragments.stream().forEach(
                f -> {
                    if (f.getImplementation().isPresent() &&
                            QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getImplementation().get().getClass())) {
                        modifiedFragments[0] = modifiedFragments[0].append(RepositoryFragment.implemented(
                                new CustomQuerydslJpaRepositoryIml((QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor) f.getImplementation().get())));
                    } else {
                        modifiedFragments[0].append(f);
                    }
                }
        );
        return modifiedFragments[0];
    }
}
```

Finally the `CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean`. This must be registered with the Spring Boot application, to make Spring aware where to get the repository implementations from, e.g. with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.package",
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
...
```

Here now the class:

```
public class CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, I>, S, I> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, I> {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean} for the given repository interface.
     *
     * @param repositoryInterface must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new CustomJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This test case has a cleaner version of running queries using querydsl

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutorUnitTests.java

```java
        JpaEntityInformation<User, Integer> information = new JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<>(User.class,
                em.getMetamodel());

        SimpleJpaRepository<User, Integer> repository = new SimpleJpaRepository<>(information, em);
        dave = repository.save(new User("Dave", "Matthews", "dave@matthews.com"));
        carter = repository.save(new User("Carter", "Beauford", "carter@beauford.com"));
        oliver = repository.save(new User("Oliver", "matthews", "oliver@matthews.com"));
        adminRole = em.merge(new Role("admin"));

        this.predicateExecutor = new QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<>(information, em, SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE, null);
        BooleanExpression isCalledDave = user.firstname.eq("Dave");
        BooleanExpression isBeauford = user.lastname.eq("Beauford");

        List<User> result = predicateExecutor.findAll(isCalledDave.or(isBeauford));
        assertThat(result).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(carter, dave);
```